Is there any way that we can access server file from server url?
For ex , My server URL is : https://example.com.
And there is one file in server folder i want to access that i didn't add in my code.
For example: APK filename is demo-example.apk
I want to access this file in browser like this:
https://example.com/demo-example.apk
I don't know the way how can i achieve this.
I want to download this file from web-browser.

If you are trying to configure a webserver to serve a file, you will need to give a lot more information on what you tried, what you're using and how you got stuck. There's lots of ways to do this, but we know nothing about your situation.

Also which protocol to use to serve the file can highly impact the decision. Should it be via web-browser, ftp, ssh, WebDAV, Samba, etc.

I want to download this file from web-browser. This file in in the server's project folder and i want to directly access the file like this : https://example.com/demo-example.apk
